# Notation: "$+$" exponent sign

Tags: notation

I'm following this [paper](http://www-stat.stanford.edu/~tibs/lasso/lasso.pdf) and came across some notation that I don't know; I've tried a number of queries such as "power to the plus", "plus exponent" etc but can't seem to find anything:

From page 4:

$\text{sign}(\beta_j)(|\beta_j| - \gamma)^+$

The "$+$" exponent is what I'm confused about.

Comment: Did you try looking up the paper by Donoho and Johnstone? They seem to get similar results in a different context based on what the authors suggested. Maybe what $^+$ means will be more clear there.

Comment: Great question. A good example of why authors should take steps to define all but the most standard notation...

Comment: I think the definition is $a^{+}:=max\{0,a\}$.

Comment: I love it. "The solutions... are easily shown to be [insert domain-specific or sparsely-defined notation here]."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The notations $f^+$ and $f^-$ for (real valued) functions and constants denote what RGB hints at the positive and negative part, respectively.

In detail $f^+ = \max \{0, f\}$ and $f^- = - \min \{0, f \}$, so that $f = f^+ - f^-$.

See the wikipedia page [Positive and negative parts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive_and_negative_parts).